# How to pass height property as ref in functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am trying to get an SVG to change height depending on container height. I am getting a height but it is not the exact height of the container div.

Here is my functional component

```js
const getHeight = (heightRef) => {
    return heightRef.current !== null ? heightRef.current.clientHeight: '200';
};

const getWidth = (heightRef) => {
    return heightRef.current !== null ? heightRef.current.clientWidth: '200';
};

const Services = ({ classes }) => {
    const heightRef = useRef(null);
    const [BGHeight, setBGHeight] = useState("500");
    const [BGWidth, setBGWidth] = useState("500");
    useEffect(()=>{
        setBGHeight(getHeight(heightRef));
        setBGWidth(getWidth(heightRef));
    },[])
    return (
        <div className={classes.Container} ref={heightRef}>
            <div className={classes.BGContainer} style={{maxHeight: BGHeight}}>
                <BGSVG width={BGWidth} height={BGHeight} color={'BGOpacity'} />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

This is my SVG

```js
const test2 = ({width, height, color}) => {
    return (
        <svg viewBox={`0 0 210 297`} width={`${width}px`} height={`${height}px`}>
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="myGradient" gradientTransform="rotate(90)">
                    <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#F8E097" />
                    <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#F2CD5C" />
                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path class={color} d={`m 0.22287672,94.082764 c 0,0 17.63282128,-34.831303 110.42670328,-36.348656 63.66595,-1.041057 101.55017,-59.333835 101.55017,-59.333835 L 211.66521,${height} H 0.75741577 Z`} fill="url('#myGradient')"/>
            <path class={color} d={`m 0.22287672,94.082764 c 0,0 37.63282128,-34.831303 120.42670328,-36.348656 63.66595,-1.041057 101.55017,-59.333835 101.55017,-59.333835 L 211.66521, ${height} H 0.75741577 Z`} fill="url('#myGradient')"/>
        </svg>
    );
};
```

An example of what is happening is my container div is showing a height of "2836.59px" in my chrome dev tools but the height getting passed down to the SVG is "2569".

I have tried doing a workaround where I just make the SVG larger and have the above overflow hidden, but I would prefer to get it working as I intended. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edited to fix issues mentioned by Mike**

Comment: Normally a viewBox would be constant. Why do you think it needs not to be? What effect are you trying to achieve?

Comment: you probably want to change svg height width and height not viewBox

Comment: I'm a noob with SVG so I assumed the viewbox was the same as a containing div height and width. For example if I increased the height there it would increase the overall image height.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `width="..."` and `height="..."` attribute in addition to the `viewBox` attribute. Without them, you haven't actually told whatever renders this SVG document how big it should be:

- The `viewBox` is for indicating how to "crop" the document: any content defined in the document, but outside the viewbox, will *not* be rendered (unless the aspect ratio of physical dimensions disagree with the viewBox). Note that these values don't have any unit attached to them, because SVG coordinates are unit-less
- The `width`/`height` attributes are used to indicate at what "physical" size to render the "`viewBox` cropped" document at. These values *do* have a unit, because they tell whatever is rendering the SVG how much space in *its* document it should take up.

So `<svg width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 10 20">`, for example, will render all the content from the SVG document that falls inside the crop rectangle (0,0)/(10,20), corrected for the aspect ratio (so it'll actually pad the viewBox on the left an right), scaled to a document size of 100px by 100px:

```css
svg { background: white; border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 20" width="100px" height="100px">
  <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
  <rect fill="green" x="-10" y="5" width="10" height="10"/>
  <rect fill="blue" x="10" y="5" width="10" height="10"/>
</svg>
```

Here the SVG document itself is rendered at 100px by 100px, with the content cropped to (0,0)/(10,20), which *should* be the red rectangle only, but the physical aspect ratio doesn't match the viewbox, so content around the viewBox gets rendered to fill in the gaps.

Matching the viewBox and physical aspect gives the expected result:

```css
svg { background: white; border:1px solid black; }
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 10 10" width="100px" height="100px">
  <rect fill="red" x="0" y="0" width="10" height="10"/>
  <rect fill="green" x="-10" y="5" width="10" height="10"/>
  <rect fill="blue" x="10" y="5" width="10" height="10"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation I appreciate it. I have added this line of code to my svg but I am still not seeing the desired results. For example my container div is showing "2836.59px" in my chrome dev tools but the height getting passed down to the SVG is "2569". <svg viewBox={`0 0 210 297`} width={`${width}px`} height={`${height}px`}>. As a side question to your exaplanation, could the viewbox values could be used as coords for a makeshift spritesheet?

Comment: They can, but CSS positioning is _much faster_ than updating an SVG viewBox attribute, so I wouldn't recommend it. As for the update: please show the full SVG code in your post as an edit, so others can also comment on what might still be wrong.